# Using nannou.rs, how can I provide the correct parameters to the load_from_image_buffer method?

Tags: rust, wgpu-rs

I am currently trying to learn Nannou.rs. I generate a Luma8 image (corresponding to a Perlin heightmap) and I am trying to display it in my app's window using the function load_from_image_buffer implemented by [`nannou`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/index.html)`::`[`wgpu`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/wgpu/index.html)`::`[`Texture`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/wgpu/struct.Texture.html#) in the model function as follow:

```
fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    let img_buf = NoiseBuilder::generate_image(256, 8, 8, None);

    let texture = wgpu::Texture::load_from_image_buffer(device, queue, usage, &img_buf).unwrap();
    
    Model { texture }
}
```

As you can see, in this snippet I am not defining the device, queue and usage parameters. I tried multiple things but nothing worked, and online resources are rather scarce.

So my question really is how can I provide this parameters?

I played around first with the from_image function and it worked, but as I am trying to learn my way around the library I am interested in the use of this specific function. Also this parameters are required by many other methods and I ll need to understand it anyway.

- The wgpu module imported in the snippet above is the nannou::wgpu and not directly the wgpu crate.
- The NoiseBuilder::generate_image return an `ImageBuffer<Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>>` variable.

Comment: What did you try, and what does "nothing worked" mean, compile time error? runtime error? expected vs actual behaviour.

Comment: I tried to supply the device, queue and usage parameters to the load_from_image function. But I don't know how to generate them in the context of a Nannou app.
I tried to provide the app variable in place of the device, queue and usage but as it was expected the types mismatch.
The code cannot run as I cannot provide this parameters.
I am looking for a way to provide this parameters in the context of a Nannou app.
(I suppose there must be a way to infer device, queue and usage from the App but I dont know how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trait method [`with_device_queue_pair`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/wgpu/trait.WithDeviceQueuePair.html#tymethod.with_device_queue_pair) which is defined in the trait [`WithDeviceQueuePair`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/wgpu/trait.WithDeviceQueuePair.html) and implemented for either [`App`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/app/struct.App.html) or [`Window`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/app/struct.App.html).

The usage is just the normal [`wgpu::TextureUsages`](https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/wgpu/struct.TextureUsages.html).

So if you would like to mimic the [`from_path`](https://github.com/nannou-org/nannou/blob/9c660fe66d07d69f9bfa7f495ceb7b24dc10a340/nannou_wgpu/src/texture/image.rs#L96) function of the texture you could do something like this (untested):

```rust
fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    let img_buf = NoiseBuilder::generate_image(256, 8, 8, None);

    let usage = nannou::wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_SRC |
                nannou::wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_DST |
                nannou::wgpu::TextureUsages::RENDER_ATTACHMENT;
    
    src.with_device_queue_pair(|device, queue| {
        let texture = wgpu::Texture::load_from_image_buffer(device, queue, usage, &img_buf).unwrap();

        Model { texture }
    })
}
```

Comment: The function itself works! I d like to precise that to be able to use the Nannou draw.to_frame method I had to add the following usage:        nannou::wgpu::TextureUsages::TEXTURE_BINDING;
Thanks!